# Groupby max value and return corresponding row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

My dataframe consists of students, dates, and test scores. I want to find the max date for each student and return the corresponding row (ultimately, I am most interested in the student's most recent score). How could I do this in pandas?

Let's say my dataframe looks like this (an abbreviated version):

```
Student_id  Date     Score
Tina1       1/17/17   .95
John2       1/18/17   .8
Lia1        12/13/16  .845
John2       1/25/17   .975
Tina1       1/1/17    .78
Lia1        6/12/16   .89
```

This is what I want:

```
Student_id  Date     Score
Tina1       1/17/17   .95
Lia1        12/13/16  .845
John2       1/25/17   .975
```

I found this on SO but it gives me a positional indexers out-of-bounds error.

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('student_id').apply(lambda x: x['date'].idxmax())]
```

What are other approaches to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the data frame by Date and then use `groupby.tail` to get the most recent record:

```
df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%m/%d/%y').argsort()].groupby('Student_id').tail(1)

#Student_id     Date    Score
#2     Lia1 12/13/16    0.845
#0    Tina1  1/17/17    0.950
#3    John2  1/25/17    0.975
```

Or avoid sorting, use `idxmax` (this works if you don't have duplicated index):

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%m/%d/%y').groupby(df.Student_id).idxmax()]

# Student_id       Date Score
#3     John2    1/25/17 0.975
#2      Lia1   12/13/16 0.845
#0     Tina1    1/17/17 0.950
```