# pandas getting max and min for a specific other column value

Tags: pandas

I have following sample data-set.

```
 raw_data = {'name': ['Willard Morris', 'Al Jennings', 'Omar Mullins', 'Spencer 
 McDaniel'],
            'age': [20, 19, 22, 21],
            'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', "green"],
            'grade': [88, 92, 95, 70]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
 df.head()
```

I am interested in finding max, min grade for a specific color say 'blue' how can i find it out.

The solution i have is following.. is there a better way. I have a huge data-set performance is also a criteria while selecting options available.

```
for i in df.index:
    if df.at[i, 'server_ip'] == 'blue':
        if min_grade > df.at[i,'grade']:
           min_grade = df.at[i,'grade']
        if max_grade < df.at[i,'grade']:
           max_grade = df.at[i,'grade']
```

Comment: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Comment: `df[df.favorite_color == "blue"]["grade"].min()
df[df.favorite_color == "blue"]["grade"].max()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groupby max value and return corresponding row in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976352/groupby-max-value-and-return-corresponding-row-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use .loc here

```
df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='blue','grade'].max()
df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='blue','grade'].min()
```

## Edit 1

If you don't want to search twice, just save the result of .loc first then conduct the aggregation

```
data = df.loc[df['favorite_color']=='blue','grade']
min = data.min()
max = data.max()
```

## Edit 2

If you want to search max and min for every color, use `groupby`

```
grouped = df.groupby('favorite_color')['grade']
max = grouped.max()
min = grouped.min()
```

Comment: When we are finding max why can't we find min also?. Can't we stop multiple iterations?.

Comment: See edits ... also feel free to hit that green check to the left!

Comment: I was looking for a solution to find max and min for all unique values of favorite_color. Any solutions?

Comment: In that case, you should use groupby